# How do I implement a resolver for a GraphQL abstract field whose type is determined by its sibling field?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

### Problem

I'm using [apollo-server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/) to implement a GraphQL server that sits on top of a REST API.

The REST API returns an entity whose root-level field determines the shape of another root-level field. i.e...

```js
{
  "entityType": "foo",
  "entityMetadata": { /* based on value of `entityType` */ },
}
```

In the GraphQL schema, the field whose shape is determined by the value of its sibling, is an abstract type. I want to write an [apollo-server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/) resolver for that abstract field. I think I should use [`__resolveType`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/#interface-type) but I'm having trouble doing so because the args that I'm passing to the abstract field's `__resolveType` method do not include any way for me to reference the sibling field's value.

So what do I do?

### Another Example

I'll use the following GraphQL schema to illustrate my issue.

```
type Character {
  job: String!
  weapon: Weapon
}

interface Weapon {
  yearMade: Number
}

type LightSaber implements Weapon {
  yearMade: Number
  color: String
}

type Blaster implements Weapon {
  yearMade: Number
  ammo: Number
}

type Query {
  searchCharacters: [Character]
}
```

With this schema, I have a `Character` type with `job` and `weapon` fields. That `Character`'s job determines the type of the weapon they'll use.

So if the `Character`'s `job` is `"jedi"` their weapon *should* be of the `LightSaber` type with an exclusive `color` field. If the `Character`'s `job` is `"stormtropper"` their weapon will be of the `Blaster` type with an exclusive `ammo` field.

I want to search all available characters with the `searchCharacters` query and return their character data *and* their weapon's exclusive data depending on the weapon's type.

```
query {
  searchCharacters {
    type
    weapon {
      yearMade

      ... on LightSaber {
        color
      }

      ... on Blaster {
        ammo
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for all character data, but I hit a snag when I try to resolve the `weapon`'s type. So far, I have this:

```js
const Weapon = {
  __resolveType: async ({ yearMade }, context, info): "LightSaber" | "Blaster" => {
    // how do I resolve whether it's a LightSaber or Blaster?
  },
};
```

Originally, I was under the impression that the `parent` field of the `__resolveType()` function would be the resolved `Character` object (i.e. `{ type: 'jedi', weapon: { yearMade: 8, ...otherWeaponProperties }, ...otherProperties }`), but it's actually just the field's current object (i.e. `{ yearMade: 8, ...otherWeaponProperties }`).

*If* I could access the `Character`'s `type` field, I'd be able to determine what the weapon type is, but *I can't*.

### Potential Solutions

I have seen two solutions to this problem.

#### Solution #1

The first solution was to append the `Character`'s `job` value to the `weapon` object (i.e. `{ job: 'jedi', yearMade: 8, ...otherWeaponProperties }`) and that way the `__resolveType` function for the `Weapon` field has access to the job value in its first argument.

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    searchCharacters: async () => {
      return api.getCharacters().map(apiCharacterData => {
        return {
          // --- start of important change ---
          ...apiCharacterData,
          weapon: {
            ...apiCharacterData.weapon
            job: apiCharacterData.job,
          }
          // --- end of important change ---
        };
      });
    },
  },
  Weapon: {
    // --- first arg is object `{ job, ...apiCharacterData.weapon }`
    __resolveType: ({ job }) => {
      return job === 'jedi' ? 'LightSaber' : 'Blaster';
    }
  },
}
```

#### Solution #2

The second solution was to change the underlying schema so that instead of a generalized `Character` type, there are `Jedi` and `Stormtrooper` types that implement a `Character` interface, and these types explicitly detail the type they'd have for the `weapon` field.

```
interface BaseCharacter {
  job: String
  weapon: Weapon
}

type Jedi implements BaseCharacter {
  job: String
  weapon: LightSaber
}

type Stormtrooper implements BaseCharacter {
  job: String
  weapon: Blaster
}

union Character = Jedi | Stormtrooper

type Query {
  searchCharacters: [Character]
}
```

```
query {
  searchCharacters {
    ... on Character {
      job
      weapon {
        yearMade

        ... on LightSaber {
          color
        }

        ... on Blaster {
          ammo
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then I only really need to add `__resolveType` to the `Character` union type and not the `Weapon` type.

```js
const Character = {
  __resolveType: ({ job }) => {
    return job === 'jedi' ? 'LightSaber' : 'Blaster';
  },
};
```

### Help!

Between the two potential solutions, solution #2 seems like a step in the right direction. The biggest gain of solution #2 over solution #1 is that I don't have map the api data and I let the resolvers do what resolvers need to do per entity.

**But** the nested nature of the query and the inclusion of the `... on BaseCharacter` inline fragment makes me feel like I'm misunderstanding how to properly write a GraphQL schema that models what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm pretty sure this isn't an uncommon problem, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve it. All help is appreciated.